# Is there any kosher considerations in regards to offal / tripe?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

If you ignore our often modern sensibilities in regards to meat eating, for argument sake. Is there any kosher consideration in regards to the less desirable parts of animals. Is questions in regards to kosher considered in regards to the whole animals or is there certain cuts of meat that can be considered to not fulfill to Kashrut when the animal itself does?

Comment: Yes you can eat it - https://dinonline.org/2020/02/24/kashrut-of-tripe-and-kishke/

Comment: (Not a [kosher consideration](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44086/759), but often enough some tripe really belongs to a kohen and you'd have to buy it from him.)